# Creating variable from other variables in MATLAB: code with reproduction

Tags: matlab, variables

I have a question regarding this type of code:

```
First = ["A","B","C"];
Second = ["D","E","F"];
Group = ["First", "Second"];
for gr = Group
    current = gr;        
    for number = 1:numel(current)                
        my_variable(number) = current(number);     
    end
end
```

That's the reproduction of my problem. In this case `my_variable` is equal to `"First"` for example. But I wanted it to be `"A"` then `"B"` then `"C"` from variable named `"First"`.

For my understanding this code should do the following:

- 1st step: `for gr = Group`  means gr = First to Second
- 2nd step: `current = gr;`   means current = First
- 3rd step: `for number = 1:numel(current)` means number = 1:3 (number of elements in "First")
- 4th step: `my_variable(number) = current(number);` means my_variable = First(1) = "A"

Instead of that I get `my variable` equal to `"First"` or `"Second"`.

I hope you understand what I mean.

---

P.S. the [string arrays](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) I'm using with double quotes (`" "`) like `First = ["A","B","C"];` are only available in Matlab 2016b or later.

Comment: You have misinterpreted step 3. `numel(current) = numel('First') = 5` as in there are 5 elements in the string `First`. You *could* do `numel(eval(current))` which would evaluate the variable from the string, but please don't - using `eval` is bad practice, especially when easily avoidable like here. Instead try using structs or cell arrays

Comment: Thank  you for your comment! Now I see where my understanding is different from what Matlab wants to do. Unfortunely, changing those variables to cell arrays/structure arrays,  doesn't change the bad output (still get the name of the variable "First" or "Second" instead of corresponding value, for example "A" or "B". I will try this method with eval instead :(.

Comment: Also, method with "eval" certainly works for counting (step 3), but that's not the solution to my real problem described above. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What do you actually expect the output to look like here? Because even if this did what you expected, you would over-write `my_variable` with the values in `Second`, and those extracted from `First` are lost...

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I can repair it later. The real thing is that I want to store two variables in another one, and I want to use that other one in a loop. What I need for my solution is the loop where firstly it takes every element of the first variable (i.e. from variable First, it takes "A", "B" then "C"; and then in a loop it takes every element from variable Second - "D", "E", "F"). I made an error with creating this variable "Group" for loop, because in code it's always a string or structure or cell, but it never creates the "link" to real existing variable "First" or "Second".

Comment: It would be much better if you could describe what you're trying to achieve. I appreciate your minimal example, but it sounds like you're making this much harder than it should be. For instance why not just concatenate them to start with (`all_things = [First, Second]`) and loop through each element? Consider editing your question to clarify the actual task at hand.

Comment: I cannot concatenate them, because my code is far longer, and after one loop I save my whole structure as a seperate file to use it in other MATLAB plugin (SPM). And I want to do that for each of those "smaller" variables (here: First, Second). This code is a part od SPM batch to calculate t-tests between fMRI brain images: it's really long, so I think it wouldn't be clear and convinient to paste it here. Hmm, maybe I need to think about other solution for my whole code, and not only for this part... Thank you for answering all the time :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [cell arrays](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) to do this:

```
first = {'A','B','C'};
second = {'D','E','F'};
group = {first, second};
for group_ind = 1:numel(group)
    current = group{group_ind};
    my_variable = cell(1,numel(current));
    for number = 1:numel(current)
        my_variable{number} = current{number};
        disp(my_variable)
    end
end
```

For `first` and `second`, you can also use the string arrays:

```
first = ["A","B","C"];
second = ["D","E","F"];
group = {first, second};
for group_ind = 1:numel(group)
    current = group{group_ind};
    my_variable = strings(1,numel(current));
    for number = 1:numel(current)
        my_variable(number) = current(number);
        disp(my_variable)
    end
end
```